# Moving object which is referred

Tags: c++

I have two structs:

```
struct A
{};

struct B
{
    A& a;
};
```

and initialize them `A a0; B b{a0};`. But now, I want to move object `a0` to new one:

```
A a1{std::move(a0)};
```

I don't know how to inform `b` that the value of it's member `a` should be changed. It's impossible to change value of standard reference, so I was thinking to change it into `std::reference_wrapper` or something similar. But still there is a problem - how to inform object `b` (specifically - its member which now is some kind of smart reference) that value of field `a` should be changed?

I was thinking about observer pattern, where `A` will be **subject** and `B` member referring to `A` will be **observer**. After moving subject, it will send all observers its new address. It may be solution, but maybe there is something easier?

---

As appendix, why I use something like that. In my project, I have another structure (simplified version below):

```
struct C
{
    A a;
    B b{a};
};
```

`A` is wrapper to memory (pointer to memory is given to `A` in constructor, but here not mentioned to keep it simple), it knows size of allocated memory and how to write and read it. `B` is object which knows how to insert some values to memory (i.e. how to insert `int32_t` - in **LE** or **BE**, how to serialize compound object). This two structures are in some closed library (company library, so I can open issue to change it, but it is used in some other projects, so I must be sure what kind of changes I need and are they **really** necessary). `C` gives me interface to put only specific objects into memory - I get only raw memory to construct it, so I must handle creating objects `A` and `B` inside it and outside `C` nobody needs to know what dependencies I use to write into this memory.

Structure `C` should be movable, because it will be returned using `std::optional` - its constructor is private and there exists static method `create` which builds object of `C` depending on status of some other operations needed to construct it (here described simply using `bool` argument):

```
static std::optional<C> create(bool v)
{
    return v ? std::optional<C>{C()} : std::optional<C>{};
}
```

To tests, I also write constructor of `C`:

```
C()
{
    std::cout << "C::C()" << std::endl << &a << std::endl << &b.a << std::endl;
}
```

and function which is trying to build this object:

```
auto c = C::create(true);
std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
std::cout << &(c.value().a) << std::endl;
std::cout << &(c.value().b.a) << std::endl;
```

Here is result of executing this test:

```
C::C()
0x7ffe8498e560
0x7ffe8498e560
main
0x7ffe8498e570
0x7ffe8498e560
```

which shows that `C` member `b` holds wrong reference now.

I'm open to criticism, because I know it could be bad design and maybe I should do it in some other way.

Comment: Fix your `C` move/copy constructor. default one is not what you want.

Comment: it looks like you shouldn't be using a reference in case you want to move it later

Comment: as I understood that the core of your problem" : "It's impossible to change value of standard reference," ... the "value of a reference" is the value of the variable it references, thats just how references work

Comment: @user463035818 maybe it was too big shortcut, I was having on my mind that it's impossible to change variable which is referred, it always points to the same variable. And because that, I was thinking about some smart reference. But still exists problem how to inform it, about moving referred variable

Answer (score 2):

Your class C should be:

```
struct C
{
    C(const C& c) : a(c.a), b(this->a) {}
    C(C&& c) : a(std::move(c.a)), b(this->a) {}

    A a;
    B b{a};
};
```

Then your reference is still valid.

Comment: It works with minimal example, but in situation when `B` is not so simple, it will lose its state, because it will be rebuild, not moved.

Comment: @3mbd3v You can write a `B::B(B &&, A &)`, that moves the state of the old `B` into the new `B`

Comment: @Caleth I think that this is soultion I was looking for. It needs some changes in library which implements `B`, but it is the most simple soultion.